# Power BI | group by in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a "data" table and there is an column "period" -

| period |
| --- |
| 1 year |
| 3 year |
| 1 year |
| 2 year |
| 3 year |
| 3 year |

I want my output to be -

| year | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 year | 2 |
| 2 year | 1 |
| 3 year | 3 |

please help me to get this output

Comment: Add Year to the table as dimension and =count(table_name[year]) as measure. This should solve your issue.

Comment: Did the answer below help or how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table:

```
newTable = SUMMARIZE(
            Tabelle, /// select table
            Tabelle[period], ///
            "Count", /// give name for value col 
            COUNT(Tabelle[period])) /// define function
```

**Output:**

[image]